# Identify girl (brown hair, white dress, pink crisscross lace)

Tags: the-idolmaster

I saw someone using this as an avatar somewhere:
[image: unknown character]
Is this character from any series, or is she just art?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be [Hagiwara Yukiho](http://idolmaster.wikia.com/wiki/Yukiho_Hagiwara) from [THE iDOLM@STER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Idolmaster), which is originally a video game series with several anime and manga adaptations. The series is about the lives and careers of a number of fictional idols in Japan, mostly working with the fictional studio 765 Productions. Yukiho is a 16 year old girl (17 in more recent versions) who is one of the idols. She's known for her timid personality and fear of dogs and men, which she is able to overcome as an idol.

Here's a higher quality uncropped version of the same picture (click for full size):

[image]

I haven't yet tracked down the source of this image.

Comment: Yes. The girl who is afraid of dogs but can dig holes at super-human speeds.